# Creating a Mosaic out of multiple images increases the luminance of the final image

Tags: c#, image-processing, asp.net-core

I am trying to create a collage of images with Magick.net. I am using **MagickImageCollection** and **.Mosaic()**. I tried already a few of the functions provided by **MagickImageCollection** but all of them increase the brightness of the final image. The only one that worked so far was **.Montage()**, but with **.Montage()** I don't get the padding right.

How do I need to configure it, that **.Mosaic()** keeps the colors as they are in the single images?

```
using (var collection = new MagickImageCollection())
{
    for (var i = 0; i < thumbnailCount; i++)
    {
        var image = new MagickImage(TempThumbPathFor(i));
        image.Resize(256, 0);

        var posX = (image.Page.Width + margin) * (i % 2);
        var posY = (image.Page.Height + margin) * (i / 2);
        image.Page = new MagickGeometry(posX, posY, new Percentage(100), new Percentage(100));

        collection.Add(image);
    }

    using (var result = collection.Mosaic())
    {
        result.Write(newPath);
    }
}
```

Collage of images with washed out colors:
[image: Generated Image]

For more information why the problem occurred in the first place have a look at this issue: [GitHub](https://github.com/dlemstra/Magick.NET/issues/409)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out how to create a montage with padding and proper color. Couldn't get it to work with **.Mosaic** but with **.Montage()**.

The important part is to add the margin to X, Y, Height and Width and call **.Trim()** on the final image. You will most likely have to play around a bit with the margin to get a balanced looking padding between the images, but other than that it works quite well.

```
const int margin = 2;
MagickGeometry geometry = null;
using (var collection = new MagickImageCollection())
{
    for (var i = 0; i < thumbnailCount; i++)
    {
        var image = new MagickImage(TempThumbPathFor(i));
        image.Resize(256, 0);
        collection.Add(image);

        if (i == 0)
        {
            geometry = image.BoundingBox;
            geometry.X += margin;
            geometry.Width += margin;
            geometry.Y += margin;
            geometry.Height += margin - 1;
        }
    }

    using (var result = collection.Montage(new MontageSettings()
    {
        Geometry = geometry,
        BackgroundColor = MagickColor.FromRgb(255, 255, 255)
    }))
    {
        result.Trim();
        result.Write(newPath);
    }
}
```